# Empty N1QL result set

Tags: couchbase, sql++

On my couchbase bucket I have a bucket (myBucket) which contains 1.7 billion documents. I have a primary index on the bucket that should make myBucket fully queryable.

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX 'my_primary' ON myBucket
```

The issue is that I cannot get ANY results from N1QL. All responses are empty. Even doing something as simple as:

```
SELECT * from myBucket LIMIT 1;
```

Winds up returning an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some basic information about your setup, server version, document size. Also, check logs (especially indexer.log and query.log) if it has reported any errors/warnings.

To make sure sanity of the setup, can you first try with a smaller dataset, or rather create a partial index on smaller amount of data and try the query using that index. Based on that we can guide you further.

-Prasad